# Communicating with hiveserver2 using Golang

Tags: go, hive

I have hortonworks HDP sandbox installed inside Oracle Virtual Box. And I've given access to port 10000. In hive configurations hiveserver2 thrift port is set to 10000 also. I'm using https://github.com/derekgr/hivething wrapper to get the connection. Even though hiveserver2 is running I can't seem to connect with the wrapper mentioned above.

I tried the sample program. But it doesn't go anywhere after " db, err := hivething.Connect("127.0.0.1:10000", hivething.DefaultOptions)" line. It doesn't even reach the if condition beneath it. So it's trying to get the connection and stays just as that.

What am I doing wrong?

Is there anymore good wrappers that works with hiveserver2?

Comment: Have you found anything about this? I had a similar issue and it was about SASL authentication. Disabling SASL got me connected but I need SASL, any idea about that?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so I'll post this as an answer.

Check if hiveserver2 is actually listening by trying to

> telnet localhost 10000

from your VM first, then from your machine.
It should show you where to look at first.

Comment: Port is open and works fine. Because when I access legacy hiveserver via port 10000 from Mr.mattbird's legacy wrapper I can insert,update, query the data in hive. I wanted to use hiveserver2 because I need to use Apache Ranger with it.

Comment: I have the exact same issue (i.e. it just hangs) on a small test cluster here. Maybe you could file an issue to hivething.